# Socket's sendTo() doesn't send any packet unless I explicitly sleep the thread

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, udp, wireshark

I'm facing a pretty strange behavior these days. I am developing, on Visual Studio 2015, a C# program which sends udp frame to a remote host. I have the following code :

```
Socket soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
byte[] char_send = new byte[1] { Convert.ToByte('l') };
soc.SendTo(char_send, send_IPEndPoint);
EndPoint listen_EndPoint = soc.LocalEndPoint;
IPEndPoint listen_IPEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)soc.LocalEndPoint;
soc.Close();
```

Nothing happens. Can't see anything on Wireshark.

However, if I sleep the thread for 1ms right after the sendTo(), the frame is correctly sent.

```
Socket soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
byte[] char_send = new byte[1] { Convert.ToByte('l') };
soc.SendTo(char_send, send_IPEndPoint);
Thread.Sleep(1);
EndPoint listen_EndPoint = soc.LocalEndPoint;
IPEndPoint listen_IPEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)soc.LocalEndPoint;
soc.Close();
```

How is it possible? I'm obviously missing something here, I just can't figure out what.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are closing the `Socket` right after calling `SendTo()`.

`Socket`s are only logical constructs what actually happens is the data to be sent is copied to system buffer, then the OS takes care of actually sending out the bits over the network.. Since you are closing the `Socket` which disposes it and releases unmanaged resources you are telling the OS to release resources related to the `Socket` which releases the data that has not actually been sent out over the network yet..

One workaround could be adding an ACKnowledgement - so the receiver sends you a small datagram once it has received yours - then you can close your socket. In fact since UDP does not guarantee delivery you may want to do this anyway.. Alternatively if you just want to fire and forget Thread.Sleep() works too.

PS: The correct term is a "Datagram" when referring to a user's UDP packet. "Frame" tends to be used for ethernet level packets..